# How to remove the specific character in between using Apache rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a URL like http://example.com/abc+def+cde+ndk

Unfortunately the number of capturing groups in the URI (abc, def,cde..) are not in a fixed number.

I tried writing a rule like the below but it is matching and replacing only three groups(two character groups and one + in between).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)(\+{1,})(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://example.com/%1%3 [R=301,L]
```

Example given below:

Source: example.com/abc+def+cde+x+y(n number of strings separated by +)
Destination Must be: example.com/abccdexy...till n

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Please update the question with your intentions for the rule.

Comment: Source: http://example.com/abc+def+cde+x+y(n number of strings seperated by +)                                                                                                                         Destination Must be: http://example.com/abccdexy...till n

Comment: Thanks, I provided an answer.

Comment: Please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a directive to the main config, the best solution is to use a `RewriteMap` that processes the URL rewriting through an external script, which you write. You can find [details on that here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg).

Basically you do something like:

```
RewriteMap convertUrl "prg:/www/bin/convertUrl.pl"
RewriteRule \+ ${convertUrl:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

(only the `RewriteMap` needs to go in your main config, the `RewriteRule` can go in your `.htaccess`)

Where `/www/bin/convertUrl.pl` is a script you write to process the substitution, as described on the above link. It should take the URL on  STDIN (without any buffering), strip out the plus signs, and return it on STDOUT.

Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1; # Turn off I/O buffering
while (<STDIN>) {
    s/\+//g; # Replace dashes with underscores
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: He is using .htaccess and RewriteMap doesnt work on this context. Could you post an htaccess based solution?

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer to point that out. I will think on a pure `.htaccess` solution.

Comment: I added a pure `.htaccess` solution as a second answer.

Comment: My IBM HTTP server is not supporting rewrite maps. I need .htaccess solution. The solution which was given earlier is replacing only once and executing only once. Please help with a .htaccess answer if possible.

Comment: Please try it again, I had made a mistake when adding the /help/col part, it should work now. It is a .htaccess answer.

Comment: Did you try again? It should work fine. Let me know any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure `.htaccess` solution.

```
# Remove a plus sign on each iteration of the rule
RewriteRule ^help/col/([^+/]+)\+([^/]+)$ help/col/$1$2 [E=REMOVED_PLUS_SIGNS:1]
# For URLs that were processed, redirect once all the plus signs are removed
RewriteCond %{ENV:REMOVED_PLUS_SIGNS} =1
RewriteRule ^help/col/([^+/]+)$ /help/col/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the rule RewriteRule ^([^+/]+)\+([^/]+)$ $1$2 [E=REMOVED_PLUS_SIGNS:1] will execute in a loop.                                                          It's actually removing only one plus, since it's parsed only once.

Comment: Because mod_rewrite rules are looped through until they return the same URL again. Have you tried it? It works perfectly, tested here, and is not only parsed once, which appears to be an assumption you are making.

Comment: Actually i need to redirect a specific URI so I added the below rule.                                RewriteRule ^/help/col/([^+/]+)\+([^/]+)$ https://example.com/$1$2 [E=REMOVED_PLUS_SIGNS:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REMOVED_PLUS_SIGNS} =1
RewriteRule ^/help/col/([^+/]+)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Correct me if i made any mistake

Comment: That should do it. Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll take a closer look. Please accept the answer with the tick at the top left of it to show it answered your query.

Comment: Sorry, actually yes you need to remove the slash at the start as that is not included in a .htaccess match. And add 'help/col/' before $1 in the last rule. And remove example.com from the first rule. And trust people answering questions to know what they're doing. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Let me explain the issues i faced. With the first approach in which perl script is included apache service doesn't come up(i installed apache in windows and changing httpd.conf)                                                                                                                   I also tried the same rule you posted but it is still replacing only one plus from the URL. The problem is not with the / as you mentioned. The rule which is setting the environment variable REMOVED_PLUS_SIGN is executing once and removing exactly one plus.

Comment: Well the other solution is best, with the Perl script. Check your error log and see why it wouldn't come up. You might need to install Perl or something else. The error log will explain. This one works fine for me on CentOS.